# Information regarding urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am new to Django, I have started learning just a week ago. I am taking the reference of Django Docs, but I can't understand how to give url to an app. So can anybody please tell me how to give url to an app with description?

for example:- If I want to make a login form and when I click on login button it goes to the home page.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/ start here

Comment: Agreed: have you worked through the tutorial Daniil linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is a web framework

A web framework carry out common works for you(the web developer)

One of the common works is resolving the http request

One of the resolving is direct the request pointing to a URL to a specific piece of code which handles this request and generate the response.

We sometime call the stuff carrying out the above mechanism a ***URL router*** of the web framework. The piece of code in Django is a function(which generate a http response), we call it the ***view***.

So we say the framework's ***URL router*** map a URL to a ***view***.

You tell the ***router*** what URL maps to what ***view*** by listing your url-view mappings in the solo ***urls.py*** in the root directory of your project

If you dislike the solo ***urls.py*** being too large, you can split this file into multiple files, and put them in individual Apps directory. Then by using ***include*** syntax you aggregate them into the solo ***urls.py***